# Cargar tabla sin datos en mat-table angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Estoy haciendo el llenado de una tabla web en angular por medio de una servicio.ts que va y trae datos de un api, hasta aquí todo bien, pero no logro hacer que de inicio no me cargue datos (de preferencia me gustaría cargar solo headers), sino hasta que compruebe que un valor 0 haya sido cambiado, esto lo puedo hacer desde un botón que tengo. Quiero pensar que es una condición para saber el estatus y si debe de entrar a según si se cumple la condición.

Les dejo el código de mi *servicio.ts*:

```
 getUsers(filters: FiltersReporteo): Observable<Logs> {
 if(filters.Uniop !== 0 && filters.Uniop !== null)
 {
  let params;
  if (filters.Uniop !== null) {
  params = new HttpParams()
    .set('OrderDirection', filters.OrderDirection)
    .set('PageSize', filters.PageSize.toString())
    .set('PageNumber', filters.PageNumber.toString())
    .set('OrderBy', filters.OrderBy)
    .set('SearchPattern', filters.SearchPattern)
    .set('Start', filters.Start)
    .set('End', filters.End)
    .set('Regla',filters.Regla)
    .set('TipoActor', filters.TipoActor)
    .set('Uniop', filters.Uniop.toString());    
  }

  if (filters.Uniop === null) {
  params = new HttpParams()
    .set('OrderDirection', filters.OrderDirection)
    .set('PageSize', filters.PageSize.toString())
    .set('PageNumber', filters.PageNumber.toString())
    .set('OrderBy', filters.OrderBy)
    .set('SearchPattern', filters.SearchPattern)
    .set('Start', filters.Start)
    .set('End', filters.End)
    .set('Regla',filters.Regla)
    .set('TipoActor', filters.TipoActor)
  }
return this.http.get<Logs>(`${this.url}/panel/pagina`, { params });
}
else
{
  //Aqui me gustaria poner las instrucciones, pero no lo he logrado
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La validación podrías hacerlo desde tu *component.ts* usando estados booleanos. Habría que ver como llamas en principio a tu *service* para cargar tu tabla.

Por otro lado repites mucho código en tu service. Capaz el código de abajo te dé una idea de como validar para enviar los parametros.

```
getUsers(filters: FiltersReporteo): Observable<Logs> {
let params = new HttpParams();
if (filters.OrderDirection) params = params.set('OrderDirection', filters.OrderDirection);
if (filters.PageSize) params = params.set('PageSize', filters.PageSize.toString())
// ... resto de params
if (filters.Uniop) params = params.set('Uniop', filters.Uniop.toString()); 
 
return this.http.get<Logs>(`${this.url}/panel/pagina`, { params });
}
```